# Design rationale behind search bit for directories

Tags: permissions, executable

Execute permission can be reasoned as a special program access control mechanism. The search permission on the other hand is described like this in the POSIX specification for an error code for `open`

> [EACCES]
>   Search permission is denied on a component of the path prefix, or ...

and for `fchdir`

> [EACCES]
>   Search permission is denied for the directory referenced by fildes.

Why is search permission mandatory for `cd'ing or traversing down a directory? What security rationale was there? Why does it has to be separate from read permission?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to have a folder as mailbox receiving messages from others. You certainly do not want a stalker list (read permission) your directory to find scoops about you. Yet you need to allow the folder to be writable (at least to the people you know). *Hence* why search permission is separate from read permission, and the security rationale.

As to why is search permission mandatory for `cd'ing to and traversing down a directory, because *it's been separated by design* as mentioned in the first paragraph.